# How to get custom attribute name for action in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, attributes

I have created an attribute for action names. I want to get the attribute names in my service. I tried so many solutions but it doesn't return anything.
This is my attribute class:

```
public class CustomeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is the action that I used the attribute for:

```
   [Custome(Name ="ُShow courses")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var course = _courseService.GetAllCourses();
        return View(course);
    }
```

This is the method that I want to return the attribute name:

```
 public IList<ActionAndControllerName> AreaAndActionAndControllerNamesList(Assembly asm)
    {

        var contradistinction = asm.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .SelectMany(type =>
                type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
       BindingFlags.Public))
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Controller = x.DeclaringType?.Name,
                //Action = x.Name,
                //Action=x.DeclaringType?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomeAttribute), false),
                // 
         
       Action=x.DeclaringType?.CustomAttributes.Where(c=>c.AttributeType==typeof(CustomeAttribute)),
                // Action=x.DeclaringType?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomeAttribute), false),
                // Action=x.DeclaringType?.CustomAttributes(typeof(CustomeAttribute), false),
                //Action=x.DeclaringType?.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(CustomeAttribute), false),
                Action=x.DeclaringType?.GetCustomAttributes<CustomeAttribute>(),
                //Action = x.DeclaringType?.GetCustomAttributes().Where(a => a.GetType() == 
          typeof(CustomeAttribute))
                Area = x.DeclaringType?.CustomAttributes.Where(c => c.AttributeType == 
           typeof(AreaAttribute)),
               
            });
        }
```

As I said I tried the solutions above that are commented but none of them worked. What should I do?

Comment: not sure what you mean by `none of them worked`, at least there should be some data returned although it may not be what you want (e.g: you want a string but the returned data is an `IEnumerable<Attribute>`). Try this `Action = x.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttribute>()?.Name` - That should work, note about the extension generic method `GetCustomAttribute<T>` which requires the namespace `System.Reflection`.

Comment: Thank you but it returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.I shouldn't have used "DeclaringType" in service.
This is the solution:

```
var contradistinction = asm.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .SelectMany(type =>
                type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
           BindingFlags.Public))
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Controller = x.DeclaringType?.Name,                  
                Action = x.GetCustomAttribute<CustomeAttribute>()?.Name,
                Area = x.DeclaringType?.CustomAttributes.Where(c => c.AttributeType == 
             typeof(AreaAttribute)),
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to save `Name` to some place in ActionfilterAttribute.Here is a demo to save data to session in `OnActionExecuting` method:

TestController:

```
        SomeOtherClass _someOtherClass;
        public TestController(SomeOtherClass someOtherClass)
        {
            _someOtherClass = someOtherClass;
        }
        [Custome(Name = "Show courses")]
        public IActionResult TestActionFilterAttribute()
        {
            var Name = _someOtherClass.TestGet();
            return Ok();
        }
```

SomeOtherClass:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private ISession _session => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;

        public SomeOtherClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public string TestGet()
        {
            return _session.GetString("Custome_Name");
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs(`IHttpContextAccessor` can help get seesion outside controller):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddSingleton<SomeOtherClass, SomeOtherClass>();


        }
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();

        ...
    }
```

CustomeAttribute:

```
public class CustomeAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
       

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext
                                           context)
        {
            if (Name != null) 
            {
                context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Custome_Name", Name);
            }
      
        }


        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext
                                              context)
        {
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you but is there any way to get it in the method by GetCustomAttribute like those ways I tried or the CustomAttribute that I used to get areas?